# How to Subtract a Vector Path from a Rectangle in Sketch

Tags: sketch-3, sketchapp

How does one subtract a vector path in Sketch. Shapes are straightforward and text is also doable. The white lines in the attached images need to be cuts through the rectangle. Suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 10):

**You need to convert the vector-path to outlines first.**

1. Select the desired element with outlines
2. Choose inside the menu: `Layer > Convert to Outlines` (⇧⌘O)
3. Select the elements you want to combine
4. Choose (Subtract, Intersect or Difference)

[image]

> **Update:** added an inline GIF for better visual reference